# What values should be provided for DataNucleus' L2 cache size

Tags: caching, datanucleus

With DataNucleus' L2 cache configuration, the "datanucleus.cache.level2.maxSize" is used to configure the cache.

The [docs](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/persistence_properties.html#cache) say that -1 is the default, and imply that this is turned on.

I'm guessing that -1 therefore means provide a cache up until some sort of -Xmx heap limit; but is that right?

If some other value is used, what are the units?  Is it number of cached objects, bytes used, Mbytes used, something else?

Answer (score 0):

number of objects, for the L2 cache providers that support that.